# Comparing cell arrays of different types in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Premise: I found something that seems to be related to my problem, but I'm not sure how to use it, thus I'm asking a new question.

I have a cell matrix, call it A, which would look something like this:

`[ 'string' 'string' 'number'`

'string' 'string' 'number'

........................... ]

and I need to compare a cell array I just created, call it `B = ['string' 'string' 'number']`, with matrix A to see if B is already there somwhere. If I try touse ismember, matlab returns an error because an argument is not a string.

What should I do?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, so this answer is only valid if these assumptions are:

- You really mean cell arrays and not char arrays in 2nd dimension as
  your code snippets suggest.
- Your cell arrays A and B have the same number of elements in the 2nd
  dimension.

The following line will return a column vector of ones and zeros, where a one indicate a match of the B elements with a row in X:

```
sum(cellfun(@isequal,X,repmat(B,size(X,1),1)),2)==size(X,2)
```

Brief explanation:

- repmat replicates B to the size of X.
- cellfun compares every single element in the two matrices.
- sum counts the number of string matches in each row.
- == checks if all elements in a given row matches.

Hope it helps

Comment: it helps a lot actually! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure which variables you have, but this may work:

Turn everything into a string and then use ismember, for example:

```
['string' '_' 'string' '_' num2str(number)]
```

Make sure to do this on both inputs of ismember.

---

Depending on the size of your variables, it may be easier to just attach everything (or everything that is unique) to B and then run `unique` afterwards.

Comment: The problem with doing this is that I actually need the floating point number to be an actual number, and conversions take up a lot of time.

Comment: Updated post including a second method, its performance depends on your variables of course.